# jquery stops execution after trying to append element

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is supposed to copy insides of element twice, and append them, but for some reason jQuery stops executing after first append. I do not understand why.

```
$(".testowyUl").prepend(function () {
  var $temp = $(this).children().clone();
  var $temp2 = document.createElement("div");
  $temp2.append($temp);
  $temp2.append($(this).children().clone());
  return $temp2.children();
});
```

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle link that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) on a non Jquery object at

```
$temp2.append($temp);
```

resulting in

```
Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'append'
```

#### update:

you could try by using

```
var $temp2 = $("div");
```

instead of

```
var $temp2 = document.createElement("div");
```

see a working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/Ufgx4/)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var $temp2 = $("<div>");
```

instead of:

```
var $temp2 = document.createElement("div");
```

to create a jquery object. As there is no method "append" in DOM element.